# How to delete inline css with no class or id in wp_head()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

```
 <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style media="all">
Bounce of code
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='...' href='...' media='all'/>
<script>...</script>
...
</head>
```

I want to delete `<style media="all"> Bounce of code </style>` part of the head. It is in the wp_head(). Is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your template files and remove it there.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution except debugging the whole website and it's theme/plugin is to simply add this in the end of your theme's `functions.php`:

```php
function start_wp_head_buffer()
{
    ob_start();
}

function end_wp_head_buffer()
{
    $in = ob_get_clean();
    $in = preg_replace('/' . preg_quote('<style media="all">') . '\s*' . preg_quote('Bounce of code') . '\s*' . preg_quote('</style>', '/') . '/s', '', $in);

    echo $in;
}

add_action('wp_head', 'start_wp_head_buffer', 0);
add_action('wp_head', 'end_wp_head_buffer', PHP_INT_MAX);
```